# What does this joke between Dean Martin and Frank Sinatra mean?

Tags: meaning, humor

I have been listening to Dean Martin Pandora radio lately and there is a song medley between Sinatra and Martin. During each song they have little quips back and fourth, and there is one that I don't seem to understand

> Frank: "Do you have a fairy godmother?"
>   Dean: "No, but I got an uncle we keep a close eye on."

What is the meaning behind this joke?

Comment: The allusion is to *fairy* = homosexual, a common pejorative back in the days when homosexuals and paedophiles were conflated in the minds of many.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand why you've added paedophiles to this

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam They mean that homosexuals and paedophiles were combined in the eyes of many people back then.

Comment: Yeah, @stanri, I got that part. But I don't see that as relevant to the joke.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam it is because a paedophile is someone "we keep a close eye on"

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team: The "relevance" has changed over time. When Dean Martin said this, it was in the context of a society where it was *normal* to make that association. Many younger people today might not even realise this, in which case they might see his reply as just a meaningless non-sequitur. But many of those who *do* know of the (hopefully, *historic*) association would tend to see it as offensive  (regardless of whether the actual word "fairy" is seen as pejorative rather than just "dated").

Comment: That association did exist, but I suspect that "keep a close eye on" comes more from an unspoken fear that a homosexual would make a pass at me, Dean Martin, an adult male, rather than make a pass at some kid.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there was much implication of pedophilia.  It was about homosexuality.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @FumbleFingers' interpretation, especially given the fact that the relative under watch is an uncle: the term *funny uncle* was, at one time, commonly understood to mean a male relative who was known or suspected to be either gay, a child molester, or (probably, in the minds of the relatives) both. You can still find examples of this usage today. The conflation of homosexuality and pedophilia and the suggestion that a pedophile is just a bit "funny" is extremely offensive on multiple levels, and thus this joke should not be repeated in a modern context.

Comment: @Hot Licks: From the track *Fiddle About* on The Who's *Tommy* back in the 60s... [I'm your **wicked Uncle Ernie** \ I'm glad you won't see or hear me \ As I fiddle about \ Fiddle about \ Fiddle about! \ Your mother left me here to mind you \ Now I'm doing what I want to \ Fiddling about \  Fiddling about \ Fiddle about! \ Down with the bedclothes \ Up with your nightshirt! \ Fiddle about \ Fiddle about \ Fiddle about!](http://www.metrolyrics.com/fiddle-about-lyrics-who.html) Uncles were / are stereotypically ***paedophiles***, not homosexuals.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In this quip, the term *fairy* is being used to imply homosexuality. "Fairy" is a somewhat archaic term for homosexuality that today would be considered offensive.

> Nels Anderson in The Hobo (1923) said that “Fairies or Fags are men or boys who exploit sex for profit.” The word fairy appeared in the 1870s, and was universally understood by the 1890s.

(From Rictor Norton's ["A History of the Word 'Gay' and Other Queerwords"](http://rictornorton.co.uk/though23.htm))

The joke comes from Frank's use of *fairy godmother* to mean the fairy tale character, a woman with magical powers who brings good fortune to someone (as in Cinderella), and Dean using the term *fairy* to connote homosexuality. Dean is saying "I have an uncle that we suspect might be gay, so we watch him closely." The "keep a close eye on" also suggests that homosexuality is something to worry about or police, so the joke reinforces homophobic norms (not at all surprising given the context).

Comment: I am a milennial whose first language is English and I have never heard the word fairy used like this before. I'm very glad that English is (albeit slowly) losing these terms.

Comment: That's such a gay comment! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers ikr? lol

Comment: @Kodos: I do *try* to keep up. At least I know how to use ***gay*** and ***lol*** (unlike David Cameron, who's much younger than me, but apparently thought the latter meant [Lots of Love](https://www.cnet.com/uk/news/britains-prime-minister-thought-lol-meant-lots-of-love-so-what/)) But I must admit you almost had me on the ropes with ***ikr*** (luckily, Google helpfully explained it to me when I hovered my mouse over it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers For a while in the early-to-mid 2000s, I saw many (non-digital native) people use 'lol' to mean 'lots of love' or, more commonly, 'lots of laughs', rather than its accepted definition today: laugh out loud. Coincidentally, it seemed the % of users using it for 'lots of love' was positively correlated with the users' ages.

Comment: @TylerH: I got into online chat back in the 20th century (only *just* - I started in 1998). I'm sure none of the people I interacted with then were under any such illusion. We also often used variants such as LMAO, ROFL, which have pretty much disappeared already.

Comment: @FumbleFingers we've clearly been frequenting different spheres, then! lmao, rofl, etc. are still *very* common, along with newer ones like smh, kmsl, the list goes on... Unfortunately I can't claim regular 20th century internet activity; I didn't start in earnest until 2000.

Comment: @stanri My last name is Ferry so I can confirm many people are still aware of its original meaning both young and old.

Comment: @FumbleFingers http://cdn.parentsshouldnttext.com/img/aunt-died.jpg

Comment: Hmm, the quote defines 'gigolo's, not homosexuals.

Comment: @TylerH - The year 2000 is the 100th year of the 20th century.

Comment: @GRW I don't count it that way.

Answer (score 14):

A common meaning for *fairy* is homosexual (most dictionaries warn that this use is offensive), and that is one of its uses here. The usual meaning of *fairy godmother* is a magical woman who watches over the indicated person (often seen in children's stories). See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fairy
for both meanings of *fairy*.

So Frank is asking if there is someone who (magically) watches over Dean, and Dean is saying that he has an uncle whom the family suspects is gay. When explained this way, it doesn't sound funny at all, but the original is (somewhat) humourous.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple gay joke.  Others have claimed it involves paedophelia and that it is perhaps offensive.  No.  It's just lowbrow humor from a few decades ago.